# Quando é recomendado Inicializar uma propriedade final no construtor da Classe?

Tags: classes, construtor, dart, flutter

O exemplo abaixo é um resumo do original ([Bringing it all together](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro#bringing-it-all-together)) encontrado na página oficial do Flutter.

Na primeira chamada, a classe *Cart* é inicializada pelo construtor e na segunda *Cart2*, não.

Como se percebe o resultado é exatamente o mesmo, então fiquei na dúvida, é apenas uma 'gurmetização' do código ou tem alguma vantagem/recomendação para inicializar uma propriedade no construtor da classe?

```
class Produto {
  const Produto({this.nome});
  final String nome;
}

void main() {
  Cart(produto: Produto(nome: 'Hd 1TB'), disponivel: true);
  Cart2(produto: Produto(nome : 'Hd 2TB'), disponivel: false);
}

class Cart {
  final Produto produto;
  final bool disponivel;
  Cart({Produto produto, this.disponivel}) : produto = produto 
  {
    print('Produto: ' + produto.nome);
    print('Disponível: ' + disponivel.toString());
  }  
}
/*
   Resultado:
   Produto: Hd 1TB
   Disponível: true
   Produto: Hd 2TB
   Disponivel: false
*/
class Cart2 {
  final Produto produto;
  final bool disponivel;
  Cart2({this.produto, this.disponivel})
  {
    print('Produto: ' + produto.nome);
    print('Disponivel: ' + disponivel.toString());
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você utiliza a forma da classe `Cart` você pode realizar validações.

Ao utilizar o `:` é inicializadas as "Listas inicializadoras" que são expressões executadas antes dos construtores da `superclass`, logo são executadas também antes de executar o `constructor` da classe `Cart`, assim essa forma normalmente é utilizada para verificar os parâmetros passados para o `constructor` da classe, assim podendo realizar alterações neste parâmetro antes de finalmente setar seu valor à variável `final` que não poderá ser modificada após o `constructor` ser executado.

Fonte: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013532/10145630)

No caso do seu exemplo, é apenas duas formas diferentes de se fazer ou como você disse "gurmetização".

Eu prefiro utilizar a forma da `Cart2` pois economiza processamento e é uma forma mais limpa.

**EDITADO**

Você pode validar por exemplo a quantidade de itens para exibição

```
class Cart {
  Cart(bool limitItens, int itensToDisplay)
      : limitItens = limitItens,
        itensToDisplay = limitItens ? 10 : itensToDisplay;

  final int itensToDisplay;
  final bool limitItens;
}
```

No exemplo é validado se o `limitItens` é `true`, assim se verdadeiro é limitado a uma quantidade de 10 itens para exibição.
Cada parâmetro do `constructor` é separado por virgula também após o ":"

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981594/10145630

*Obs.: Estou sem o Flutter aqui no momento para dar exemplos mais completos.*

Comment: `...você pode realizar validações.` De que tipo? Poderia exemplificar?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Verifique a seção **EDITADO**, adicionei um exemplo de validação.

Answer (score 2):

O segundo é *syntax sugar* do primeiro, e na verdade o segundo parâmetro do primeiro ainda é um *syntax sugar* e vai ocorrer com ele o mesmo que ocorreu com o outro parâmetro.

Essa sintaxe colocando o `this` no parâmetro indica que você deseja que ele automaticamente deva ser atribuído para o campo com mesmo nome.

O fato de ser `final` é irrelevante para esta questão em específico, apenas faz diferença se você tentar inicializar o campo dentro do construtor, aí se torna um problema porque a inicialização precisa ocorrer antes de qualquer processamento.

O termo propriedade está equivocado, na documentação eles usam o termo variável de instância (em algum momento até usam genericamente o termo propriedade em algum ponto de forma ambígua, o que indica que a documentação não é boa ou a própria linguagem não é bem definida, o que dá medo). Em alguns documentos vi o uso do termo campo. Algo genérico sobre o assunto pode ser lido em [outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Fique na dúvida sobre qual termo utilizar, vi aqui (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) o seguinte:
`Dart supports top-level variables, as well as variables tied to a class or object (static and instance variables). Instance variables are sometimes known as fields or properties.`

Comment: "Essa sintaxe colocando o this..."  está se referindo a `named arguments`?

Comment: não, estou falando dos parâmetros, no caso dos construtores.